# in typescirpt, how to assign the value of enum to type?

Tags: typescript

I have assign an enum, like `ColorKind`. now I want to get a type, it can use values of enum, alse can use the literal value.

Of course, I can explicitly declare `ColorType`. It works but not good.

```
enum ColorKind {
    Red = 'red',
    Blue = 'blue',
}
type ColorType = 'red' | 'blue'
type Color = ColorKind | ColorType

let color: Color = ColorKind.Blue
color = 'red'
```

I try to use `Record` to mark it work, however it's not works

```
type ColorType = keyof Record<ColorKind, string>

let color: Color = ColorKind.Blue
    color = 'red'
//  ^^^^^ error!
```

Comment: I suggest you to avoid `enum`s and just use literal union types: `type Color = 'red' | 'blue'`. See also https://paper.dropbox.com/doc/WTF-TypeScript-fyxWXDfqYssUzsAzmGmZL#:uid=001751238087574856185399&h2=Should-I-be-using-enums?

Answer (score 0):

The point of having an enum, is to use that enum to assign values from. If you plan on assigning `red` and `blue` to things without going through the enum, just use a union type, as Denis suggested.